# How to Change iFrame location in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

window.frames["the_iframe"].location.href =someurl;
Works in IE but doest not work in FF . how it will work in FF or other browser.

Thanks in advance.

Please help

Comment: Is the_iframe name or ID?

Answer (score 0):

add name parameter to the frame,

```
name='the_iframe'
```

try this, hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick assistance I could able to do with some thing else for FF. As this "window.frames["the_iframe"].location.href =someurl" was working in IE and Chrome.